# Another pattern for Dynamic/Expanding forms?

Tags: forms, design-patterns

Usually we just have a table rows with Delete row and Add new row button.

But what if there's just too many columns? Can't provide a mockup since I'm just thinking on top of my head.

A closest I can find on google image is this: [image: expanding table]

I am thinking of a table and a button that would open a modal with the form inside. Spacing issue is solved here because the inputs are vertical.

The problem tho is, after closing that modal, how should the inputted data look like in the table? Less column?

Currently not having this issue but who knows when I will be needing it. I just cant really think of a solution on how to solve this issue.

Must also say that wizard might not be applicable since it is a group of related data rather than "relationship" like

Answer (score 4):

> I am thinking of a table and a button that would open a modal with the form inside. Spacing issue is solved here because the inputs are vertical.

Yes you are heading in the right direction. It is better to avoid the form elements inside grid or a table for following reasons:

1. It is confusing for the user while entering data when there
   considerably more rows.
2. Developer might kill himself while implementing this! form entry
   through modal is more elegant and easy both design and
   implementation wise.

> The problem tho is, after closing that modal, how should the inputted data look like in the table? Less column?

You can show data after entering from modal as below.

[image]

as per this you can actually maintain fixed height rows which will look more systematic and expands if more link is clicked on the address field.(Which I think the only field here that will consume more lines.)

**Update:**

> What if there's many column? I'll be needing a lot of horizontal space there

So in that case keep the horizontal scroll to table by keeping the actions column as fixed one. so that it is always visible on the right most end.
I mean make each column expandable horizontally ex.[check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24590718/expandable-contractable-columns-with-100-width). but
try to squeeze as much space as possible to avoid initial horizontal scroll. hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for this because now I know it is still bad even if there is less columns but the problem with this is: the problem asked in OP still exists. What if there's many column? I'll be needing a lot of horizontal space there. It looks good inside the modal because it's vertical but when it gets back to the table.... what now? That's what I meant.

Comment: @jen I have updated the answer, hope it helps.